# nullpointerexception when use getIntent().getExtras().getString

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I want to pass a value in a activity to another activity and use this code

```
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("position","ایران");
            startActivity(i);
```

and in other activity for return variable use this code

```
        value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("position");
```

Now when I run the program it gives this error:

```
java.lang.nullpointerexception
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the right way to retrieve string extra:

```
value = getIntent().getStringExtra("position");
```

**Explanation**

Why getExtras() does not work: 
getExtras() returns a bundle which was previously put inside intent using putExtras(bundle). 
so, the code would look like:

```
    // Put position inside intent using extras:
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("position",position);
    intent.putExtras(extras);

    // Retrieve position:
    getIntent().getExtras().getString("position");
```

But that's a lot more code, storing extra inside the intent directly is much more cleaner way

Comment: thanx , please help me about this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799958/twice-opening-activity-with-an-null-value